Why am i facing "APPEND_SLASH" error in Django?
So i am creating a simple API sing Django. So every time i am getting the APPEND_SLASH issue while making a POST request on localhost:8000/cars from PM , in the body I am passing a JSON request body with one field based on the value of which the data is gonna be filtered from the sqlite DB.
Also , i am unable to find "APPEND_SLASH" in my settings.py!!
Below is the error message:
RuntimeError: You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to localhost:8000/cars/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
My urls.py:
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
    path('cars/',views.cars,name='cars'),
    
]

My views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from cars.models import car
import json
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import JsonResponse
def cars(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        all_cars=car.objects.all()
        cars_data=[]
        for each_car in all_cars:
            cars_data.append({
                'name': each_car.name,
                'color': each_car.color,
                'fuel': each_car.fuel
            })
        return JsonResponse(cars_data,safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data=json.loads(request.body)
        color_of_car=data.get('color_of_car')
        if color_of_car is not None:
            one_car=car.objects.filter(color=color_of_car)
            output=[]
            for each_car in one_car:
                output.append({
                    'name': each_car.name,
                    'color': each_car.color,
                    'fuel': each_car.fuel
                })
            return JsonResponse(output,safe=False)

The request body i am passing in body through Postman (PM)
{ "color_of_car":"black" }
PS; Also , please suggest what else can i change if i am starting a new project from scratch in order to not face this error again?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#append-slash

And why do you try to call "localhost:8000/cars" when you defined "localhost:8000/cars/" as the correct URL?

APPEND_SLASH is true be default
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#append-slash
You will find it in global_settings.py file in the directory where django in installed. Perhaps in your virtual env directory.
